# template function error: no operator found which takes a right hand operand of type

Tags: c++

Hey! check out the following example.. its almost a copy paste from some cpp book.
i can't understand why is doesn't compile (under windows).
it says:

```
'<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'div_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

this is the example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T div(T a, T b) {
    T result =  a/b;
    return result;
}

int main() {    
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;
    std::cout << "INT " << div(a,b) << std::endl; //this line output the error

    return 0;
}
```

thanks!!

Comment: as a quick fix, this would probably work:

`std::cout << "INT " << div<int>(a,b) << std::endl;` since the conflicting `div` isn't a template.

Comment: @Evan Teran: You can actually leave the argument deduction to the compiler `std::cout << "INT " << div<>(a,b) << std::endl;`.

Answer (score 5):

`div` is a standard library function that returns a value of `div_t` type. When you included `<iostream>`, you apparently also indirectly included the declaration of the standard `div`. This is what the compiler is trying to use, not your template version.

This is probably the fault of the implementation, not your fault (assuming that the code you posted is the exact code you are trying to compile). If they include that portion of standard library in `<iostream>`, they probably should have done it in such a way that standard `div` would have become `std::div`. If they did it that way, you wouldn't have this problem.

You can do

```
std::cout << "INT " << div<>(a,b) << std::endl;
```

to explicitly ask the compiler to use your template.

Comment: @Dave: Or if you have a `using namespace std;` in your code, you imported the name yourself. The solution then would be to remove that `using` line.

Comment: @sth: Comeau Online reports the same error for this very code.